# Crash in string formatting of double

Tags: swift

We have a crash in the getter method below, but have been unable to see where the crash might be occurring.

```
extension Double {
    public var formatTrackTime: String {
        if !self.isNaN {
            let hour = Int(self / 3600)
            let minute = Int(self.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 3600) / 60)
            let second = Int(self.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))
            return hour > 0 ? String(format: "%d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second) : String(format: "%02d:%02d", minute, second)
        } else {
            return "0:00"
        }
    }
}
```

The crash log only points us to this getter, but gives no other details about the crash. Is there anything that stands out as a crash here?

[image: top of crash log]

Comment: Which inputs do your test cases cover? It’s probably not one of those ;)

Comment: Just because isNaN is a boolean doesn't mean it is a boolean state.

Comment: @Jake I didn’t downvote, but as frustrating as it is, the site etiquette doesn’t require that dow nvoters explain their decision. Clearly this is just a case of weak test coverage, and there’s some Double values this doesn’t handle properly. Many people find that to be uninteresting, hence the down votes.

Comment: You’re right, it doesn’t require people to say why. But this why new people find it so hard to contribute here!

Comment: @Jake yeah, it can be frustrating. But there’s certainly lots of things you can do to improve this question that you probably even know: share your test suite, so we can see which values you already test over. Add logging to your error report, so you can find the crashing input on the next occurrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something "off the shelf" from Swift to accomplish this without having to do a bunch of math.

```
extension Double {
    var formatTrackTime: String? {
        guard !isInfinite else {
            return nil
        }
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
        formatter.unitsStyle = .positional

        return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Some test code for a playground:

```
// 3:36:40
print(13000.formatTrackTime)
// "\n" (empty string)
print(Double.infinity.formatTrackTime)

class DoubleTests: XCTestCase {
    func testFormatTrackTime() {
        XCTAssertNil(Double.infinity.formatTrackTime)
        XCTAssertEqual(13000.formatTrackTime, "3:36:40")
    }
}

DoubleTests.defaultTestSuite.run()
```

Comment: This is usually my bias also, but I’m apprehensive of switching this out before the root cause was found. This trades one implementation and it’s known bugs with a new one and unknown bugs.

Comment: @Alexander Good point. Perhaps before swapping the implementation, identify the source of the bug. The OP could just write a unit test for the existing code and throw a bunch of scenarios at it to see what's breaking it.

Comment: I suspect there’s an infinity that made it’s way into the input, but I can’t test it right now.

Comment: This will crash for the double value being `.inifinity` and `.nan`, it could be avoided by checking for `isFinite`.

Comment: Not related to the question but it is worth to mention that this will create a new DateComponentsFormatter every time you call this property.

Comment: Had to add a nan check and made some formatting additions to get it just what we wanted, but over all this approach worked.

Comment: I'd also note that retrning `nil` is almost certainly preferable to returning `""`. You can bet that a few lines of code after where this is called, there's gonna be a `if result.isEmpty` check. Optionals are better suited to this.

Comment: `XCTAssertNoThrow` is also the wrong thing to use here. This method can *never* throw (if it did, the compiler would have required it to be marked `throws`). `XCTAssertNoThrow` does not catch runtime panics like `fatalError`, failed force-unwrapping, array indices being out of bounds, etc.

Comment: @Alexander Excellent points. I think optional is preferable here, as well, but I tried to stay faithful to the OP's original var declaration.